# Defining a Minimum cost-flow problem with piecewise costs

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, integer-programming, piecewise-continuity, network-flow

I need to formulate an Integer Linear Programming model for a Minimum cost-flow problem over a graph without constraints on edges. The cost over edges isn't linear but piecewise, given by:

$c(x_{ij})=\begin{cases}
 c_{ij}^{1}x_{ij} & \mbox{}\mbox{$0 \leq x_{ij} \leq h_1$} \\
 c_{ij}^{k+1}x_{ij} + \sum_{r=1}^{k}(c_{ij}^{r}-c_{ij}^{r+1})h_r  & \mbox{}\mbox{$h_k \leq x_{ij} \leq h_{k+1},\;\;
  k=1,..,T-1$} \\
 c_{ij}^{T+1}x_{ij} + \sum_{r=1}^{T}(c_{ij}^{r}-c_{ij}^{r+1})h_r & \mbox{}\mbox{$x_{ij} \geq h_T$} \\
 \end{cases} $

T is a given parameter,

$c^k_{ij} > c^{k+1}_{ij} \;\; per \;\; k=1,..,T$

$h^k < h^{k+1}$, $\forall k=1,..,T-1$ are constants

I tried the linearization of the minimax:

min  $\sum_{(i,j)\in A}y_{ij}$

$y_{ij}\geq c^1_{ij}x_{ij}$ $\forall (i,j)\in A$

$y_{ij}\geq c^{k+1}_{ij}x_{ij}+\sum_{r=1}^{k}(c_{ij}^{r}-c_{ij}^{r+1})h_r$ $\forall\: k\leq T-1$, $\forall (i,j)\in A$

$y_{ij}\geq c_{ij}^{T+1}x_{ij} + \sum_{r=1}^{T}(c_{ij}^{r}-c_{ij}^{r+1})h_r$ $\forall (i,j)\in A$

$\sum_{j:(i,j)\in A}x_{ij}-\sum_{j:(j,i)\in A}x_{ji}=b_i$  $\forall i\in V$

$0\leq x_{ij},\:integers$  $\forall (i,j)\in A$

with each variable $y_{ij}$ representing the cost over one edge, but it seem to be unsuitable for my problem. I also tried with the maximin but it is still wrong.
How can I define this Problem?

Comment: In the third objective, the index goes up to $T$ I suppose ? If yes, I don't understand what's wrong with your approach. As your objective function is convex and you minimize it, this is the simplest approach, what do you want more ?

Comment: @caduk you were right about the index going up to *T* so I edited it. My problem is that if I insert numbers in my formula, the result is wrong: if I use the minimax I wrote in the question or the maximin I get wrong answers, even in small graphs of 4 vertices. The maximin actually gives me a maximum cost flow problem result, but I dont know how to turn it in a minimum flow without having an unbounded objective

Comment: How bad is your solution ? Does the solver return a non optimal solution, or does it return a solution that can't be valid ? In the first case, find a better solution and check every constraint to see the one that is violated

Comment: Are you fine with getting a min-cost flow problem with capacities on the edges?

Comment: @caduk thank you but i solved it on my own, I just had to use boolean variables

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you also misha for your answer